# El .exe generado por pyinstaller no se ejecuta

Tags: python-3.x

ya use pyinstaller y auto-py-to-exe todos compilan sin mostrar error pero al momento de ejecutar el .exe hace eso necesito y ya no se que hacer. ayuda!!!
[image: error que muestra antes de cerrerse]

Comment: Lo que cuentas es poco claro. Podrias poner los scripts de configuracion de pyinstaller y auto-py-to-exe aqui de modo de que podamos ayudarte? Es una buena costumbre, sino se complica.

Comment: el problema no es el compilador ya que compile otros archivos y funcionaron perfectos.... y en mi codigo (el del error) me tira ese fallo

Comment: añade "pkg_XXX" a los hidden imports y entonces recompila el script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione formateando la pc y instalando Python 3.7.2

Comment: Vaya reinstalar todo un SO para darle solución a la instalación me parece un tanto extremo...... pero bueno a final de cuentas te sirvió, ¿no era mas simple quitar todas las instalaciones de python y derivados y de ahi solo instalar lo que mencionas?

Comment: O usar un virtualenv para evitar conflictos de librerias.